# EnumWindows strange behaviour

Tags: winapi, mfc, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use MFC with visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.
I have the following code:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EWP(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int txtlen = GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd);
    std::wstring s;
    s.reserve(txtlen + 1);
    GetWindowText(hwnd, const_cast<wchar_t*>(s.c_str()), txtlen);

    return TRUE;
}

EnumWindows(EWP, 0);
```

What happens is that the very first string comes out as "Task Switchin" and the rest come out as "". I get about 330 of these strings. I have tried without using that weird string method too with just char buff[300], same story.

Can someone please tell me whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last argument to GetWindowText() is off-by-one.  From the MSDN article description of that argument:

> Specifies the maximum number of characters to copy to the buffer, **including the NULL character**. If the text exceeds this limit, it is truncated.

Pass `txtlen+1` to fix.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the case, however my problem was not fixed. I am still getting 330 empty strings.

Comment: Actually I am getting the window names now, but after the 330 empty strings, no idea why I get so many empty ones. Thanks this is solved now.

Comment: Lots of windows don't have text.  EnumWindows is a fire hose, you see everything, including hidden windows.

Comment: @user1040769: On a side note, since you are using `GetWindowTextLengthW()` explicitally instead of `GetWindowTextLength()` generically, you should use `GetWindowTextW()` explicitally instead of `GetWindowText()` generically to match.